# Change Text Box Background Color Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have tried a few solutions I have seen and none of them are actually changing the background color of my text box.  These are the 2 things I have tried
1) `state.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"`
2) `state.style.backgroundColor = "red";`

And this is the function I am trying to use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function VerifyStateWasEntered() {
    var state;
    state = document.getElementByID("txtstate").value; 
    if (state == '') {
        alert("Error Please Enter A Valid State");
        state.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        return false;
    }}
```

And this is the HTML I am using to create the text box

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtstate" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Since you use asp control you may run into a problem with .NET generating the id. In this case you get a compound of the control nestings ("MainContent_Login1_LoginPanel" say). Check the ClientIDMode setting in the Page directive and set the value to "static" to avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?  When you assign the state to the value, you cannot get the style object from value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function VerifyStateWasEntered() {
    var stateObj;

    stateObj = document.getElementByID("txtstate");
    if (stateObj) { 
      var stateValue = stateObj.value; 

      if (stateValue == '') {
        alert("Error Please Enter A Valid State");
        stateObj.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        return false;
      }}   
    }   
</script>

<asp:TextBox id="txtstate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: Once I changed the syntax to 'stateObj = document.getElementById("txtstate");  -- It worked as needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting is possible, but I suspect you use the wrong ID (as per my comment). To set the color of an element you can use the JavaScript below.

```
document.getElementById("txtstate").style.background = "red"
```

But you need to make sure you have `ClientIdMode="static"` on the page.

Comment: I have set ClientIDMode="static" and tried your syntax, and the alert shows but the text box color does not change.

Answer (score 0):

I get that you are trying to make the background color using Javascript but you can use CSS to do that and it will be much more easier.

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtstate" runat="server" />
<style type="text/css">
#txtstate {
background-color: /* the color you want */ ;
}
```

If that still doesn't work, try removing the closing `/` from `<style type="text/css">`. Good luck!